# Amazon S3 Error Code 403 Forbidden from EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, emr

I know that this question may have been asked multiple times but I tried those solutions and it didn't workout. Therefore, asking it in a new thread for a definite solution.

I have created a IAM user with S3 read only permission (Get and List on all S3 resources) but when I try to access S3 from EMR cluster using HDFS command it throws "Error Code 403 Forbidden" exception for certain folders. People in other post has answered it to be a permission issue; which I didn't find a right solution as it is "Forbidden" instead of "Access Denied". The behavior of this error has appeared only for certain folders (containing objects) inside a bucket and for certain empty folders. It was observed that if I use native API calls then it works normally as follows:

Exception "Forbidden" when using s3a calls:

`hdfs dfs -ls s3a://<bucketname>/<folder>`

No error when using s3 native calls `s3n` and `s3`:

`hdfs dfs -ls s3://<bucketname>/<folder>`

`hdfs dfs -ls s3n://<bucketname>/<folder>`

Similar behavior have also been observed for empty folders and I understand on S3 only objects are physical files whereas rest "buckets and folders" are just a place holder. However, if I create a new empty folder then `s3a` calls doesn't throw this exception.

P.S. - Root IAM access key surpass this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you file a JIRA on issues.apache.org, HADOOP project, component fs/s3 *with the exact hadoop version you are using*. Add the stack trace as the first comment, as that's the only way we could begin to work out what is happening.

FWIW, we haven't tested restricted permissions other than simple read-only and R/W; mixing permissions down the path is inevitably going to break things, as the client code expects to be able to HEAD, GET & LIST anything in the bucket.

BTW, the Hadoop S3 clients all mock empty directories by creating 0 byte objects with a "/" suffix, e/g "folder/"; then use a HEAD on that to probe for an empty bucket. When data is added under an empty dir, the mock parent dir is DELETE-d.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I will open JIRA for it.

Comment: @AbhishekSakhuja - Did you ever file the ticket? I'm running into same error. thanks!

Comment: There's been a lot of work for Hadoop 3.1 with the S3A connector and IAM roles/assumed roles & reduced permissions. Before filing any JIRA now, download Hadoop 3.1 and see if you can reproduce it there. That'll be the first thing you'll be asked to do before anyone looks at the issue